# Cannot to connect html element with the typescript variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

I'm using the same type of function that I used in my register and login but it doesn't work on the index.

I cant find anything wrong with login and register I have a input set to submit with a form that is connected to the variable and i can listen for an event.

For example this is my login code for typescript:

```
    loginForm.addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {

        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior

        // Remove error message if exists
        document.getElementById("error")?.remove();

        // Get form data
        const formData: FormData = new FormData(loginForm);
        const formDataObject: { [key: string]: string } = {};

        // Convert formData to a JavaScript object
        formData.forEach((value, key) => {
            formDataObject[key] = value as string;
        });

        const username: string = formDataObject["username"];
        const password: string = formDataObject["password"];

        try {
            const rows: any = await api.queryDatabase("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?",

                [username], [password]);

            // If query returns any result, then log in
            if (rows[0]) {
                const user: any = rows[0];
                session.set("userId", user.userId);
                url.redirect("index.html");
            } else {
                // Throw wrong username or password error
                throw new Error(" Wrong username or password");
            }
        }

        catch (reason: any) {
            // Create error message in login-popup
            const errorContainer: any = document.createElement("div");
            errorContainer.id = "error";
            const errorMessage: any = document.createTextNode(reason);
            errorContainer.appendChild(errorMessage);
            document.getElementById("login-popup")?.appendChild(errorContainer);
        }
    });
}
```

I did the same for the index with a navbar and a acnhor instead of a submit tag and now it doesn't work.

typescript code:

```
function logout(): void{

    console.log(session.get("userId"));
    //const unorderedList: HTMLUListElement = document.getElementById("navlist") as HTMLUListElement;

    const logoutButton: HTMLAnchorElement = document.getElementById("logout") as HTMLAnchorElement;

    logoutButton.addEventListener("logout",  async (event) =>{
        console.log("te");
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior
        session.remove("userId");
        url.redirect("index.html");
    });
}

logout();
```

The 1st console log does give off the userid back in console so the connection is fine with the database.

html code:

```
<li class="hidden" id="logout"><a type="logout" id="logout" href="" >Logout</a></li>
```

I've tried changing the variable types quite a bit and changed the id as well changed up the places or names but it doesn't seem to work any bit.

Comment: You’re trying to listen to an event called “logout”. That wouldn’t

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is attempting to add a logout event listener to an anchor element with the ID logout. However, there is no logout event in JavaScript, and the anchor element is not a form element that can be submitted.

To fix this code, you should change the event listener to listen for the click event on the anchor element, and remove the call to event.preventDefault(), since there is no default behavior to prevent. Here's an updated version of the code:

function logout(): void {
const logoutButton: HTMLAnchorElement = document.getElementById("logout") as HTMLAnchorElement;

```
logoutButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    session.remove("userId");
    url.redirect("index.html");
});
```

}

logout();

Comment: thanks for helping it works perfectly now